# How to track what View is generated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, comments

I am currently working on a simple comments system.

I have a table that should store comments by following model:

```
public class Comments
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public int FromUserId { get; set; }

    public int ToUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comments are being written from one user to another on his UserPage.
I get userId from db, looking for id that corresponds my User.Identity.Name (name of authorized user) and pass it to **FromUserId**.

The question is **How can I track on whoose page user is writing comment**, in order to pass this to **ToUserId**.

UserPage is being created dynamically from db.

Comment: What do you mean _track on whose page user is writing comment_?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the following:
User 'Mark' has his own UserPage. When user 'Dean' is on Mark's userpage, he can write a comment to his profile. But in order to write 'ToUserId' field in my db I need to know whoose page is generated for Dean, whether it's Mark's page, or Molly's for example.

Comment: How does Dean navigate to Mark's page? Surely by including Mark's ID in the url, so therefore you know the ID.